# My python program says "no module named 'pygame_functions'

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to python and I am making my first game, so I might be missing something obvious. I was able to install `pygame` using the pip method in command prompt and in the start of my program I wrote `import pygame`. Everything was working fine, until I tried to make a sprite. It doesn't show up on the screen, so I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMe7xQACb8U) where he writes "from pygame_functions import". However when I try to do this it comes up in the command line with

`no module named pygame_functions`.

How can I get pygame_functions? Is it even necessary? Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is necessary to use pygame_functions. Maybe the sprite isn't showing up on the screen becuase you forgot to initialize pygame. You can simply fix that by writing: `pygame.init()`
under `import pygame` like this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
```

If that isn't the problem than you maybe forgot to update the screen. You can fix it by simply adding `pygame.display.update()` at the end of your code in your main loop. If this isn't the problem neither than please show us your code in your question.

Comment: Thankyou, all I had to do was write pygame.display.update() and my sprite showed up.

Comment: No problem. I often forget something like that. Haha. I once forgot to write pygame.init() and I don't even remember how long I had to search until I saw that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to [the repo](https://github.com/StevePaget/Pygame_Functions) and download the `pygame_functions.py` file. Put it in the same directory as the file you're getting an error in.